# Geometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$: what is this area of mathematics called?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, reference-request, terminology

I've recently studied some Optimization, and I discovered an area of math of which I did not know. I saw words such as hyperplanes, ellipsoids, supporting hyperplanes, 4-dimensional face, half-space, etc. I was able to learn about some of these specific terms from the appendix in the Optimization book, but I couldn't find out what this area of math is called. Could you please tell me the name of this field? I would like to use this name to search for an introductory book on it, but if you have a recommendation, it is more than welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably convex analysis. That said, the concepts you mentioned appear in many different areas of pure and applied mathematics. Anyway, take a look at the book *Convex Optimisation* by Boyd and Vandenberghe. The first six or so chapters are on the basic theory of convex sets and convex functions (it is here you will find definitions for most of the terms you mentioned), with the rest of the book devoted to applications. For another book that is a little older but which is seen as a standard/classic in the field, take a look at *Convex Analysis* by Rockafellar.